# How to get a correct array hashcode in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, hashcode

What is the suitable way to compute hashCode of an Array that depends on its content?

`Array.hashCode` is for the array instance:

```
val h = a.hashCode
println(h == Array(1,2).hashCode) // false

a(0) = 42
println(h == a.hashCode) // true
```

Note: It'd be better to avoid copying the whole array, to a List for example, prior to computing the hashCode

Why I ask: I use an Array in a class (as a private field) because lookup time is critical, and its content is relevant to compute the hashCode of the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1607, it says that the hashCode of Array is the hashCode from java, as scala Array are java Array. And scala could not changed it.

But it also says that scala has a suitable hashCode method in WrappedArray.
Thus:

```
val a = Array(1,2)
val h = a.toSeq.hashCode // wrapped it in a WrappedArray - no copy
println(h == Array(1,2).toSeq.hashCode) // true

a(0) = 42
println(h == a.toSeq.hashCode) // false
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `java.util.Arrays.hashCode(a)`, it's likely to be faster than `a.toSeq.hashCode` (since `WrappedArray` seems to inherit a non-array-specific implementation).

Comment: It works well for Array[Int] but I don't know how it does for other (generic) item type. I guess we would need to cast items to object in the more general case, or use some other java functions (?). In the end, I prefer relying on the scala API. But there are maybe drawbacks I am not aware of (efficiency?).

Comment: WrappedArray probably has a little overhead: it needs a simple class construction (to wrap the array) and each lookup requires an additional function call. But to my experience, it is very difficult to see the difference with direct lookup. I tried and did not manage

Comment: I've made a pull request to ensure this is no longer a concern, and it has been approved https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5551.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **MurmurHash3** algorithm directly.

```
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3

MurmurHash3.orderedHash(Array(1,2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Arrays.deepHashCode(Object[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode-java.lang.Object:A-). In scala you should use ugly:

```
java.util.Arrays.deepHashCode(array.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]])
```

This method is working for multi-dimension arrays as well